# How to map a Map of Sets in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Is there a way in JPA to map an attribute with type `Map<String, Set<Address>>`

Given the following classes:

```
class Company {
  int id;
  Map<String, Set<Address>> addresses; // Key is the country of the Address
}

class Address {
  int id;
  String country;
}
```

There are three tables:

```
tbl_company
  id INT

tbl_address
  id INT
  country VARCHAR(40)

tbl_company_address
  company_id INT
  address_id INT
```

How can I map this scenario with JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions is having an address-wrapping class, and insert Set into that class. In that case you will be able to use map (using @OneToMany, @MapKey annotations). E.g.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = ...)
@MapKey(name = "countryKey")
private Map<String, AddressWrapper> addressWrappers;
```

.. and AddressWrapper would contain `@OneToMany Set<Address> addresses;`, along with `String countryKey`.